# Execl Returns Bad Address

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, posix, exec

I would really love some debugging help in this one. I've been working on this since the morning and its 4am. (I'm suppose to deliver this in 7 hours [11am])

Everything in main.c works but when I create some child processes to run compute.c's compiled file with execl it doesnt do it and sends an error of "Bad Address".

I've attached 3 pastebin links with main.c and compute.c and a txt file containing the tables I mention below.

The program is suppose to read 2 tables with integers from a file called pinakes.txt and then by using POSIX's shared memory API to place those tables in shared memory and create processes to calculate a 'row * column' sum from them and place that sum in another table.

```
sum += A[row][i] * B[i][column] = C[row][column]
```

Everything until the line below from main.c should work properly (I debugged it numerous times).

```
ppid = getpid();
```

---

- `main.c` http://pastebin.com/iMCefaLZ
- `compute.c` http://pastebin.com/Ejp214Up
- `pinakes.txt` http://pastebin.com/h8yKXFvv

  ---

compile and then run

```
./main pinakes.txt
```

#### main.c

188 lines of code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <errno.h>

int pinA_X = 0, pinA_Y = 0, pinB_X=0, pinB_Y=0;
int pinA[10][10], pinB[10][10], pinC[10][10];

main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int pid, ppid;
    FILE *stream;
    // general variables
    int i, c, j, rc, converted, lines = 0;
    //flags
    int flagV=0, flagW=0, flagX=0, flagY=0, flagZ=0;

    //shared memory
    int dumpedArray[101];
    int size = sizeof(dumpedArray);
    int sid1 = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, size, SHM_R | SHM_W);
    int sid2 = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, size, SHM_R | SHM_W);
    int sid3 = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, size, SHM_R | SHM_W);
    int* shared_A = (int*) shmat(sid1, NULL, 0);
    int* shared_B = (int*) shmat(sid2, NULL, 0);
    int* shared_C = (int*) shmat(sid3, NULL, 0);

    if(argc!=2){
        printf("wrong number of arguments\n");
        return -1;
    }else{
        stream = fopen(argv[1] , "r");
                while((c = getc(stream))!= EOF){
            if(flagZ == 0){
                if(flagX == 1){pinA_X = c - 48;flagX = 0;}
                if(c == 88){flagX = 1;}
                if(flagY == 1){pinA_Y = c - 48;flagY = 0;}
                if(c == 89){flagY = 1;}
                if(c == 90){flagZ = 1;}
            }else if(flagZ == 1){
                if(flagX == 1){pinB_X = c - 48;flagX = 0;}
                if(c == 88){flagX = 1;}
                if(flagY == 1){pinB_Y = c - 48;flagY = 0;}
                if(c == 89){flagY = 1;}
            }
        }

        fclose(stream);

        printf("pinA[%d][%d] * pinB[%d][%d] = C[%d][%d]\n\n", pinA_X, pinA_Y, pinB_X, pinB_Y, pinA_X, pinB_Y);

        // get A
        stream = fopen(argv[1] , "r");
        i=0;j=0;
        while((c = getc(stream))!= EOF){
            if(i <= pinA_X && j <= pinA_Y){
                if(flagW == 0){
                    if(c == 87){
                        flagW = 1;
                    }
                }else{
                    if(c > 47 && c < 58){
                        pinA[i][j] = c - 48;
                        j++;
                    }
                    if(c == 13){
                        j=0;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        fclose(stream);

        // get B
        stream = fopen(argv[1] , "r");
        i=0;j=0;
        while((c = getc(stream))!= EOF){
            if(i <= pinB_X && j <= pinB_Y){
                if(flagV == 0){
                    if(c == 86){
                        flagV = 1;
                    }
                }else{
                    if(c > 47 && c < 58){
                        pinB[i][j] = c - 48;
                        j++;
                    }
                    if(c == 13){
                        j=0;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        fclose(stream);

        // print A

        printf("A={\n");
        for(j=0; j<pinA_X;j++){
            for(i=0;i<pinA_Y;i++){
                printf(" %d", pinA[j][i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("}\n\n");

        // print B

        printf("B={\n");
        for(j=0; j<pinB_X;j++){
            for(i=0;i<pinB_Y;i++){
                printf(" %d", pinB[j][i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("}\n");

        // Save pinA to shared Memory
        converted = 0;

        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            for(j=0;j<10;j++){
                converted = (i * 10) + j;
                shared_A[converted] = pinA[i][j];
            }
        }


        // Save pinA to shared Memory
        converted = 0;

        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            for(j=0;j<10;j++){
                converted = (i * 10) + j;
                shared_B[converted] = pinB[i][j];
            }
        }

        // Push size of arrays in shared memory
        shared_A[100] = pinA_X;
        shared_A[101] = pinA_Y;
        shared_B[100] = pinB_X;
        shared_B[101] = pinB_Y;

        ppid = getpid();

        for(i=0; i<pinA_X; i++){
            for(j=0; j<pinB_Y; j++){
                if(ppid == getpid()){
                    pid = fork();
                    if(pid==0){
                        if(execl("./compute", "compute", i, j, sid1, sid2, sid3, NULL) == -1){
                            printf("error exec\n");
                            printf("Error opening file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                        };
                    }else if(pid<0){
                        printf("\nDen egine h fork!\n");
                    }else{
                        wait(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //print C
        converted = 0;

        printf("C={\n");
        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            for(j=0;j<10;j++){
                converted = (i * 10) + j;
                pinC[i][j] = shared_C[converted];
                printf(" %d", pinC[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("}\n");
    }
}
```

Neither `compute.c` nor `pintakes.txt` is directly relevant to answering this question.

Comment: Using expiring pastebins as part of a question in what is supposed to be a community resource is very rude.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bad address problem arises because you run:

```
for(i=0; i<pinA_X; i++){
    for(j=0; j<pinB_Y; j++){
        if(ppid == getpid()){
            pid = fork();
            if(pid==0){
                if(execl("./compute", "compute", i, j, sid1, sid2, sid3, NULL) == -1){
```

The arguments to `execl()` must be strings; `i` and `j` are manifestly not strings (and `sid1`, `sid2` and `sid3` are the  identifiers for three chunks of shared memory).

Convert those values to strings and try again.

Your program creates the shared memory with IPC_PRIVATE, so your code in `compute.c` (which is executed via `execl()` is going to be hard to make work.  You may get away with transferring the shared memory IDs like that; I'm not sure.

I think I'd be using a single shared memory segment.

It also looked like your reading code is going to read the same data into the two arrays - but I may have been misreading it.

Finally, your PasteBin examples expire in 23 hours.  That limits the usefulness of your question.  You should really transfer the data into the question - with, I suggest, no tabs and tabstops set at 4 rather than 8.  (Or use more functions to prevent such deep indentation.)

Comment: Thank you for your time, i really appreciate it. As it seems, i wont have the time to fix my error before the deadline to present my code but it will be a great educational plus to me.

Answer (score 6):

You are passing `int`s to `execl`, those should all be 0-terminated strings. Also, the final `NULL` must be cast to `Char*`.

Comment: As i said to Jonathan thank you for your time reviewing and debugging my code, i appreciate it a lot.